# Add additional attribute to an existing document if the attribute doesn't exist elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a specific requirement were I have to add an additional attribute to elastic search index which has n documents. This has to be done only if the documents don't contain the attribute. This tasks basically involves 2 steps

*1) searching*
*2) updating*

I know how to do this with multiple queries. But it would be great if I manage to do this in a single query. Is it possible? If yes, can someone tell me how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) combined with the [exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query to update and add the new field to only those documents which does not contain the attribute.

For example, you have only one documents containing field `attrib2`, others don't have that field.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "attrib1": "value1"
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/doc/2" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "attrib1": "value21"
}'
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/doc/3" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "attrib1": "value31",
  "attrib2": "value32"
}'
```

The following [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) will do the job.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_test_index/_update_by_query" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.attrib2 = params.attrib2",
    "params": {
      "attrib2": "new_value_for_attrib2"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "attrib2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

It will set the new value `new_value_for_attrib2` to the field `attrib2` on only those documents which don't already have that field.